# Cannot stop handler and service when app running

Tags: android

I have an app starts a service in background. I want it to stop the handler which runs on this service after a process. It runs correctly if I press back button. However, if I don't press back button, if the app still runs, service doesn't stop. My methods below:

First, this method runs when the service called:

```
public void startChecking() {
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
            wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            Log.d("ssid", "Checking...");
            checkWifi(wifiInfo.getSSID());
            handler.postDelayed(this, CHECK_TIME * 1000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, CHECK_TIME * 1000);
}
```

**checkWifi** method:

```
public void checkWifi(String ssid) {
    if (ssid.equals("\"" + SSID + "\"")) {
        Log.d("ssid", "SMS sending...");
        sendSMS();
        stopEverything();
    }
}
```

And the last one. **stopEverything** method:

```
public void stopEverything() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    stopSelf();
    stopService(new Intent(this, WifiService.class));
    onDestroy();
}
```

All these methods are in the service. I call this service from my main class. How can I stop the timer and service correctly?

Comment: regarding the handler, the issue here is that you call `removeCallsbacks` when there are no callbacks, as `checkWifi` is called before `postDelayed` (postDelayed is what adds a callback to the handler.)

Comment: Could you please explain it by refactoring the code?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by considering @njzk2 's comment. Thank you.